# Yosemite disables audio output on external monitor change

Tags: macos, sound-volume

When I plug or unplug monitor so the screen configuration changes, or if I open/close the MBP lid, then:

- The audio stops
- When I try to change volume, the volume symbol is crossed like this: Ø

Can it be fixed somehow? E.g. on Skype calls it's very annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the **What If I'm Running the Stable Version?** of [this article](http://betanews.com/2014/08/26/how-to-fix-disabled-audio-in-os-x-10-10-yosemite-beta/).

> So, open System Preferences,  go to the Sound menu and then look in the Output tab to see which device is used for output.

I confirmed that when I unplugged my HDMI monitor and plugged it back in, the monitor was selected by default, but when I then manually selected Headphones and then unplugged an reconnected my monitor *again*, this time Headphones stayed selected.